# Is it possible to have an embedded locally saved HTML file that is interactive. If so, what's the embed script?

Tags: html, iframe, embed, google-sites

So I want to add this HTML file into Google Sites but I want to make it embedded into the website. I currently have the HTML file saved locally. Is this possible? I have tried using iframes but can anyone give me code. If it is not possible to do with a locally saved file, how do I change it to a global one that is accessible through Google Sites?

I have tried using widgets but none give the result I want. Is this possible with iframes? I have not tried much with iframes but as the HTML file is local, how do I make it embed and interactive on my Google Sites.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Security restrictions in browsers prevent websites loaded over HTTP from referencing URLs loading using FILE.

Even if that wasn’t the case, since the file is local to you, if someone else visited the site then they wouldn’t have the file.

If you want content in a website then you need to publish it online (by picking a web hosting service and following their instructions).